# How to resize parent window size from iframe?

Tags: firefox, iframe

I have a XUL file with iframe:

```
<window>
    <iframe src="chrome://plugin/content/options.html" 
    style="width: 290px; height: 320px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px"/>
    <script>
        window.frames[0].parent = window;
    </script>
</window>
```

How can i resize parent window size from options.html?

Comment: Not sure why you bothered to write `window.frames[0].parent = window;` because that already gets done for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within regular frames you can use "top" to get the topmost window.  I don't know about an iframe, but you could try:

```
top.resizeTo(width, height);
```